# Laravel: How to run on Local Area Network?

Tags: laravel, xampp

I have set this in the virtual host and hosts file.

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin banana.test
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\banana\public"
    ServerName banana.test
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   banana.test
```

I'm trying to avoid using "php artisan serve" and just use XAMPP.

When I go to another computer and type the 192.168.1.10/banana.test it does not work.

Comment: that "hosts" setting is valid only in localhost, and also 192.168.1.10/banana.test won't produce what you think... i think that if you want to do a similar thing, you should set a local dns server and register an A record "banana.test" to point to 192.168.1.10

Comment: Thank you for the tip Alberto. You are right and that's very helpful. I'll just use "php artisan serve".